# Dismiss AlertController and stop function call

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a `function` that displays an alert controller and a button that when clicked updates a field on a firestore database. After 15 seconds the alert is dismissed and another function is fired.

```
pickupIsRequested(){
    this.pickupRequest.pickupStatus.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);

        if(value == true){
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'You have a Pickup Request!',
                message: '<span>Princess who is 3 minutes away requests a ride</span><hr/> You have 15 seconds to accept the request!',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Accept Ride',
                        handler: () => {
                            this.driver.updateDriverInRide(true, this.driverId);
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            alert.present();

            setTimeout(() => {
                alert.dismiss();
                this.driver.updateDriverPickupRequest(false, this.driverId);
            }, 15000);
        }
    }); 
}
```

How can I stop the `function` call on the `setTimeout` method after I click on the alert controller button? Right now if I click on the button the `this.driver.updateDriverPickupRequest` still fires.

Comment: Why don't you add a bool variable that indicates whether the button has been clicked? Then you should be able to do something like `if (!buttonClicked) this.driver.updateDriverPickupRequest(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clearTimeout()` to cancel your function

```
pickupIsRequested(){
   // First you need to create your timeout
   let myTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
       alert.dismiss();
       this.driver.updateDriverPickupRequest(false, this.driverId);
      }, 15000);

  this.pickupRequest.pickupStatus.subscribe(value => {
              console.log(value);

              if(value == true)
              {
                   let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'You have a Pickup Request!',
                    message: '<span>Princess who is 3 minutes away requests a ride</span><hr/> You have 15 seconds to accept the request!',
                    buttons: [
                      {
                        text: 'Accept Ride',
                        handler: () => {
                          this.driver.updateDriverInRide(true, this.driverId);
                          // Cancel it here
                          clearTimeout(myTimeout);
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  });
                  alert.present();
              }
    }); 

}
```